# Gnome3 : remove Alt key behaviour

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I am using GNOME 3.22.2 and every time I hit Alt key, I am escaping from the window. It is really frustrating because I cannot hit shortcuts like Alt-f or this kind of things.

How to remove this Alt key behavior ?